# Generating a Developer Sandbox from another Partial Box

Tags: sandbox, developer-org

I am aware that a production org can be used to spin off individual developer sandboxes.

I am in the situation where the current project has build in a partial box.  The Production org is greenfield / empty and cannot be used to spin off a dev box.

I'd like to use the data in my partial-dev to build individual dev sandboxes (not dev-pro).

Only way I can see is a deploy of metadata.  Am I missing something here in terms of functionality SF may provide?

Comment: You mention both data and metadata, to be clear you only mean metadata?

Comment: sorry for the delay, that is correct.  I was only referring to metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use Vs code or ANT migration for moving metadata from partial to developer sandbox using metadata api.

Check steps mentioned [here](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2019/04/creating-salesforce-VSCode-IDE.html) to configure VS code for salesforce deployment.

There is [Clone a Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_clone.htm&type=5) functionality, when you clone a sandbox its data and metadata are copied to the new sandbox.  However a cloned sandbox uses the same license type as its source org. Eg. Partial sandbox can only clone  partial sandbox version.

If you are planning to move salesforce records use [salesforce dataloader](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/data-loader#:%7E:text=Data%20Loader%20is%20a%20client,data%2C%20it%20outputs%20CSV%20files.).